# How to pull Company name from Contact Card and display in Message List (Inbox)

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing Outlook VSTO add-in.
I need to get Company name which is available in sender's contact card and display it message list in Inbox.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sequence of calls to get the company name of the sender:

```
mailItem.Sender.GetContact().CompanyName
```

To present your data to users you may consider using Outlook form regions, see [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks.